# OpenVPN and client-connect scripts

Tags: openvpn, debian-wheezy

I have an OpenVPN server (2.3.2) on Debian Wheezy operating in bridged mode. Everything's working fine in terms of the client connecting and getting access to the network(s) it needs.
Im trying to add a few bells and whistles through use of the client-connect option. This is the pertinent part of the openvpn config file:

```
script-security 3 system
client-connect /etc/openvpn/scripts/clientconnect.sh
```

In an attempt to check that the script is actually run, clientconnect.sh 
consists of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "testing">>/etc/openvpn/scripts/test
exit 0
```

Simple enough.

If I run the script from the command line, as expected "testing" is appended 
to /etc/openvpn/scripts/test every time, and 0 returned.

When I connect from my client, then I get a "testing" in 
/etc/openvpn/scripts/test. Great!

But when I disconnect, and connect again, I don't get another "testing"

So, to check its *actually* being run I changed the exit value in clientconnect.sh to 1

sure enough, *every* attempt to connect from the client then failed because 
the script returns a non 0 value.

Why does it look like the script isn't being run?

BTW, if I restart the openvpn service on the server then I get "testing" once 
more, but again, nothing is written on subsequent connections.

Any pointers / Help / Mystic Incantations are all gratefully received!
Dylan

Comment: A dumb idea: what happens if you set a script for `client-disconnect` as well?  Does openvpn really thinks the client got disconnected? Another idea of the same class: could you enable management interface on the server, do `telnet localhost 1194` there and verify the client is really disconnected (after disconnecting on the client side) by executing the "status" command and inspecting its output?

Comment: By the way, I'd drop that `system` bit: it's not needed in your case.

Comment: I'm asking because OpenVPN is made to be very resilient to network outages (and it really excells at it), so unless you have something like `explicit-exit-notify [n]` in your client's configuration, disconnecting that client will look like a network outage to the server. Then, depending on how you did configue timeouts/keepalives etc, it could be a hefly amount of time before the server decides the client is really gone. You might just have not reached this condition in your tests.

Comment: Looks like you are spot on kostix. I added explicit-exit-notify [n] to the client, and now its working as expected. If you add your comment as an answer, Ill accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenVPN is made to be very resilient to network outages (and it really excells at it), so unless you have something like `explicit-exit-notify [n]` in your client's configuration, disconnecting that client will look like a network outage to the server.

Then, depending on how you did configue timeouts/keepalives etc, it could be a hefly amount of time before the server decides the client is really gone. You might just have not reached this condition in your tests.

A way to verify this is to enable the management interface in your server
then do `telnet localhost 1194` there and verify the client is really disconnected — after disconnecting on the client side — by executing the "status" command and inspecting its output.

Another, more low-tech, approach to testing this is hooking a script to the  `client-disconnect` event and see whether it runs when the client disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

to  get another "testing" , use option **log append** to file , in your case /etc/openvpn/scripts/test. the problem that first testing is overrite by second. so you don`t see it, but you get it